# Module template for a comment field is not triggering comment_preprocess_field

Tags: hooks, comments

I have a custom module in which I am trying to override a comment field's template in Drupal 9.3.

In my module file I have defined the hook_theme to override the core template in use. (*comment.html.twig*), which works, but it is not triggering the *comment_preprocess_field* hook in *comment.module* which then assigns the comment variables to the template.

My module file hook_theme is:

```
function MODULE_theme() {
  return [
    'field__field_FIELD_NAME' => [
      'base_hook' => 'field',
    ]
  ];
}
```

This works and my custom template is displayed, but it is missing the comments variables passed from *comment_preprocess_field*.

If I place the template in my theme, the *comment_preprocess_field* hook runs and the variables are added to the template, but not when done from a custom module.

Does anyone know how to get the hook *comment_preprocess_field* to run when overriding a comment field template in a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `base hook`, instead of `base_hook` (no underscore):

```
function MODULE_theme() {
  return [
    'field__field_FIELD_NAME' => [
      'base hook' => 'field',
    ]
  ];
}
```

That should invoke the preprocess as normal. You'll need to rebuild caches after making the change.

Comment: Thank you!  I should have known something was up when I searched the codebase and couldn't find any uses of 'base_hook'!